# Does a SEVIS ID on an I-20 contain an alphabet?

Tags: usa, visa

A SEVIS ID on an I-20 form issued by the U.S. government starts with a letter N.  In the following digits, does it contain a non-numeric letter?

Background: I am filling in DS-160 away from home to obtain an F-1 visa  and I have to fill my SEVIS ID in the form.  I do not have access to my original I-20, which was sent to my home, and had my I-20 sent to me by FAX.  Unfortunately, I am having hard times telling 8's from B's printed on the photocopied I-20, and I am not sure as to what really is my SEVIS ID printed on the original I-20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this link](http://j1visa.state.gov/participants/how-to-apply/about-ds-2019/detailed-description-of-the-ds-2019/) the characters after the N are all numerical.